# Cancellation law of equal in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across this gem while discussing with my friends,

If $X$ and $Y$ are two real valued random variables (not necessarily independent) that satisfy
$$X =^d X+Y$$
(where $=^d$ means equal in distribution), then does it follow that $Y=0 ~ a.s$?

My guess, after some deliberation, was that it was true and attempted to come up with a proof.

Attempt:
At first I wanted to verify if this held for finite alphabets. So then,
$$P[Y=0] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}P[X+Y = x,X=x]$$
If I could somehow substitute $P[X+Y = x,X=x] = P[X = x,X=x]= P[X = x]$, then the result would follow. Unfortunately, all that is known is $P[X+Y = x]=P[X=x]$.

I am sure there is a nice trick to getting this to work. Kindly offer me some hints in this regard. If the finite case can be solved, there should be a continuous analog which I will attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X$ take the values $0$ and $1$ with equal probability and set $Y=1-2X$.

Comment: Thank you for that counter. Though now I wonder what if $X$ was bernoulli(p)... Anyhow, I'll figure it out.

Comment: You can construct a similar counterexample for any distribution with a symmetry, that is, a distribution preserving map $x\mapsto\phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is not the identity map. That's how I thought up my example.

Comment: Thanks Byron. I'll do just that and i'll update my question with that answer when I get it.